# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when closing modal window ([NSWindow _restoreLevelAfterRunningModal]: message sent to deallocated instance)

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, modal-dialog, exc-bad-access

In my main ViewController I have the following code:

```
- (IBAction)listFunctions:(id)sender //button clicked
{
    FunctionListController *functionListController = [[FunctionListController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"FunctionList"];

    NSWindow *functionListWindow = [functionListController window];

    [NSApp runModalForWindow: functionListWindow];

    NSLog(@"done");
}
```

`FunctionListController` is the File's Owner of `FunctionList.nib` and a subclass of `NSWindowController` and implements the protocol `NSWindowDelegate`.

Here is the implementation of `FunctionListController`:

```
@implementation FunctionListController

- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{
    self = [super initWithWindow:window];
    if(self)
    {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];

    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
    self.window.delegate = self;
}

- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [NSApp stopModal];
}

@end
```

When the modal window is closed, the `NSLog(@"done");` runs and displays, however after `listFunctions` is done, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

With `NSZombiesEnabled` I get the error `[NSWindow _restoreLevelAfterRunningModal]: message sent to deallocated instance`.

**Edit:**

I am using ARC.

Comment: Are you using automatic reference counting?

Comment: I'm not sure of an answer but something I'd try just because it looks suspicious: make `functionListController` a strong property rather than a local variable so that it doesn't fall out of scope at the end of `listFunctions:`.

Comment: @PhillipMills, but when `listFunctions:` is done, the window is already closed.

Answer (score 4):

Try `[functionListWindow setReleasedWhenClosed:NO]` and hold a strong reference to your window until closing.

Answer (score 1):

In your `listFunctions` method, you first create a `FunctionListController` object:

```
- (IBAction)listFunctions:(id)sender //button clicked
{
    FunctionListController *functionListController = [[FunctionListController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"FunctionList"];
```

which is referenced through a local variable; it will be released at the end of the scope (the method itself);

you then get a reference to the `functionListController window` and run it as a modal:

```
    NSWindow *functionListWindow = [functionListController window];

   [NSApp runModalForWindow: functionListWindow];
```

This object will be retained by the `NSApp`.

However, the method exits (`runModalForWindow` will not block your thread) and `functionListController` is deallocated:

```
   NSLog(@"done");
}
```

so you get a dangling reference and a modal window owned by an object which is not longer there. Hence, then crash.

Simply, make `functionListController` a `strong` property of your class and it will work.

Your new `listFunctions` would look like:

```
- (IBAction)listFunctions:(id)sender //button clicked
{
    self.functionListController = [[FunctionListController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"FunctionList"];
    ...
```

Comment: I now get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS after closing the windows and opening it again in `listFunctions:`. (`[NSWindow release]: message sent to deallocated instance`)

Comment: Could you post your new `listFunctions`?

Comment: I didn't modify `listFunctions`, I only made `functionListController` a property of `ViewController`. I manually opened the modal window by clicking a button which called `listFunctions:`, closed the window and clicked the button again.

Comment: If you didn't modify `listFunctions`, then it's still using a local variable.

Comment: Also, if `runModalForWindow` doesn't block the thread, why does it only output `done` **after** the window is closed?

Comment: @Jim oh, edited that line to what you have, but I still get EXC_BAD_ACCESS the second time. I have declared `functionListController` like this: `@property(strong) FunctionListController *functionListController;`

Answer (score 0):

Your `functionListWindow` is a local variable in your `listFunctions:` method.  When that method finishes executing, you will lose any strong reference you have to that object, so nothing will own it and it will be deallocated.  When your modal window actually closes, it tries to send the appropriate message to its delegate, however this no longer exists.

Have you tried making `functionListWindow` an instance variable on your main view controller?